# Is Citrix Reciever for Windows capable of detecting a screen capture was taken?

Tags: citrix-receiver

Is Citrix Receiver for Windows capable of detecting a screen capture was taken? (I have read Citrix Receiver for iOS can do this)

There are so many ways to take a screenshot or snip a region of the screen through different shortcut keys.

Can Citrix Receiver detect all these methods? If not, which methods can it detect?

Comment: Nothing can detect screen capture with an external device eg: phone cam

Comment: Citrix Receiver itself doesn't block file copy, screen capturing or access to local resources. It is a medium through which you access an environment or resources and the applied policies take effect. Also, nothing is stopping one from taking screenshot on host machine.